# How can I hide a category from Contributors in the edit/add new post screen?

Tags: categories, user-access, user-roles, customization

I have a situation where I need to hide a specific category and it's children from users who are logged in as Contributors. I don't want them to see this category and it's children in the categories meta-box on the add new post screen.

I can't find a plugin (that works) to do this, wondering if someone else knows of one, or even better if there is a function I can use to do this?

Comment: Looks like I have answered my own question, I found a plugin called [Restrict Categories](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/restrict-categories/) that does exactly this.

Comment: First question, are you using any kind of plugin that easily let's you add *"capabilities"* to user *"roles"*, such as the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Example in Oct 2020**, Working answer, I went to different answers none of them works now in new WordPress.

```
function hide_categories_for_specific_user( $exclusions, $args ){

if ( ((defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) && REST_REQUEST) or $GLOBALS['pagenow'] === 'edit.php' ) && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {

   // IDs of terms to be excluded
   $exclude_array = array("12","16","17"); // CHANGE THIS TO IDs OF YOUR TERMS


   // Generation of exclusion SQL code
   $exterms = wp_parse_id_list( $exclude_array );
   foreach ( $exterms as $exterm ) {
           if ( empty($exclusions) )
               $exclusions = ' AND ( t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
       else
               $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
   }

   // Closing bracket
   if ( !empty($exclusions) )
   $exclusions .= ')';

   // Return our SQL statement

  }
   return $exclusions;
}

 // Finally hook up our filter
 add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'hide_categories_for_specific_user', 10, 2 );
```

answer final help from [Hide Some Categories in Post Editor](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hide-some-categories-in-post-editor/)

Answer (score 8):

Hi **@davemac:**

Well, I wrote this before I saw that you answered your own question so I might as well post it anyway:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (in_array($pagenow,array('post.php','post-new.php')) && 
     !current_user_can('see_special_cats')) {
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.slug NOT IN ('slug-one','slug-two')";
  }
  return $exclusions;
}
```

This code presumes that you've used a plugin like the [Members plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) to create a [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) called `'see_special_cats'` and that you've assigned it to every role that you want to have access to the categories except of course `'Contributors'`.

Since you found the plugin you may not need this, but maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that is actually VERY helpful and opens up a lot of possibilities for me.

Comment: @davemac - Glad I could help.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I know its old post but still, I was looking for the same solution. I want to hide one category from contributor role. So I used your code and it hide category even from admin! How can I hide category from contributor only and admin can see that category?

Answer (score 0):

if you want hide category from contributor but only admin can see that category then change '`see_special_cats'` to `'manage_options'` I've tested and it works hope it helps. Thanks! :)

Comment: The question is: How to change.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot over the web I found a solution,
you can pass in the ids of categories you want to hide as an array, and then paste this in your functions.php file. All categories will be shown for administrators

> $exclude_array = array("5","6","7","1");

```
function hide_categories_for_specific_user( $exclusions, $args ){

if (!current_user_can('manage_options') ) {

   // IDs of terms to be excluded
   $exclude_array = array("5","6","7","1"); // CHANGE THIS TO IDs OF YOUR TERMS


   // Generation of exclusion SQL code
   $exterms = wp_parse_id_list( $exclude_array );
   foreach ( $exterms as $exterm ) {
           if ( empty($exclusions) )
                   $exclusions = ' AND ( t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
           else
                   $exclusions .= ' AND t.term_id <> ' . intval($exterm) . ' ';
   }

   // Closing bracket
   if ( !empty($exclusions) )
       $exclusions .= ')';

   // Return our SQL statement
   return $exclusions;

  }
}

 // Finally hook up our filter
 add_filter( 'list_terms_exclusions', 'hide_categories_for_specific_user', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: it hides that category from the live site also, it only shows to a login admin user. @Shamseer do you find any solutions to hide category only inside the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

PHP with a JavaScript solution — This is reliably future-proof

```
/**
 * Hide categories for specific user
 *
 */
function hide_categories_for_csl_admin() {
    if (!current_user_can('a-capability')) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        (function() {
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                var categories_to_hide = [1,167]; //define all the category ids you want to hide
                categories_to_hide.forEach(function(category) {
                    var checkbox = document.querySelector('#category-' + category);
                    checkbox.style.display = 'none';
                });
            });
        })();
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'hide_categories_for_csl_admin');
```