# Multiple users – only allow them to manage their own terms for custom taxonomy when logged in

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

How can I allow each user to manage their own terms for a custom taxonomy when logged in on edit-tags page? user will only show & manage terms that only created by him not others for a custom taxonomy. But Admin and editor can manage all. How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the AWESOME solution MikeSchinkel :D

I just did the following updates in the code and it worked like a charm:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);

function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions ) {
    $currentScreen = get_current_screen();

    if( current_user_can( 'my_custom_capability_assigned_to_specific_users' )
            && !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) // Show everything to Admin
            && is_object( $currentScreen )
            && $currentScreen->id == 'edit-<my_taxonomy>'
            && $currentScreen->taxonomy == '<my_taxonomy>' ) {
        // Get term_id's array that you want to show as per your requirement
        $terms      = implode( ',', $term_id );
        $exclusions = ( empty( $exclusions ) ? '' : $exclusions ) . ' AND' . ' t.`term_id` IN (' . $terms . ')';
    }
    return $exclusions;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm.  You are going to need to keep track of who added which terms which you can currently best do in a usermeta field as a comma-separated list  *(I'm assuming you don't expect more than ~1000 terms per user? At lot more than then I'd worry.)*

You can store the term IDs in the usermeta field using the `'edited_terms'` hook as you see here:

- [**Any examples of adding custom fields to the category editor?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6549/any-examples-of-adding-custom-fields-to-the-category-editor/6599#6599)

Basically your code might look like this"

```
add_filter('edited_terms', 'yoursite_edited_terms');
function yoursite_edited_terms($term_id) {
  if($_POST['taxonomy'] == 'your_taxonomy'): {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ($user->ID) {
      $terms = get_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_your_taxonomy');
      $terms = (empty($terms) ? $term_id : "{$terms},{$term_id}");
      update_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_your_taxonomy',$terms);
    }
  }
}
```

Then you'll need to use the `'list_terms_exclusions'` hook to limit your terms to only the ones needed for the current user, but allowing the Administrator an Editor to see them all by adding a `'can_manage_all_terms'` capability which you can use the [**Members plugin**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) to create:

- [**How can I hide a category from Contributors in the edit/add new post screen?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8197/how-can-i-hide-a-category-from-contributors-in-the-edit-add-new-post-screen/8199#8199)

Here's what that might look like:

```
add_filter('list_terms_exclusions', 'yoursite_list_terms_exclusions', 10, 2);
function yoursite_list_terms_exclusions( $exclusions, $args ) {
  global $pagenow;
  if (current_user_can('can_manage_all_terms') && 
    $pagenow=='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=your_post_taxonomy') {
    $terms = get_user_meta($user->ID,'users_terms_for_your_taxonomy');
    $exclusions = " {$exclusions} AND t.ID NOT IN ({$terms})";
  }
  return $exclusions;
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should get you on the right track. And be sure to replace anything in the code written as `'your_taxonomy'` with a reference to your actual taxonomy.

Comment: @mike - i had done this before but i keep track by storing taxonomy_term-id[user_id] in the options table, do you think keeping the data in usermeta is better?

Comment: בניית אתרים - the options table is not bad either, but the problem is we have no taxonomy meta which is where I'd want to store it. I do like usermeta because at least it's one-to-one for the user. In reality, no solution we have available to us *(yet)* is perfect.

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Thanks for your reply. The first part of the code is not working. The user meta is not updating. Will you check?

Comment: @mha - Have you tried to debug any of it using `var_dump()` statements at various points in the function? *(I should know better than try to answer when I don't have the time to actually test the code...)*

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I have tried but the code does not work.

Comment: @mha - Can you give me more details about what doesn't work?  I can't help you understand without more details.